# Istio Kafka Wire protocol Support

Tags: istio

I am new to Istio, We are planning to use Istio as SSL Service Mesh, For Kafka in a K8S environment.

I would like to check does Istio support Kafka Wire protocol communication.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "currently no".

All searchs for an answer, eventually lead to open issues and discussions with a lot of different suggestions on  Github:[Kafka protocol filter](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2852).

Some information and overview on how may Kafka work with the service mesh, can also be found in [Kafka and the service mesh](https://www.slideshare.net/gwenshap/gluecon-kafka-and-the-service-mesh) presentation.

I will update my answer if I will find more useful info for you.